# Combinatorics in Python

Tags: python, combinatorics, directed-acyclic-graphs, bipartite

I have a sort of a one level tree structure as:

[image]

Where p are parent nodes, c are child nodes and b are *hypothetical* branches.

I want to find all **combinations** of branches under the constraint that only *one* parent can branch to only *one* child node, and two branches can not share parent and/or child.

E.g. if `combo` is the set of combinations:

```
combo[0] = [b[0], b[3]]
combo[1] = [b[0], b[4]]
combo[2] = [b[1], b[4]]
combo[3] = [b[2], b[3]]
```

I think that's all of them. =)

How can this be achived automaticly in Python for arbitrary trees of this structures i.e. the number of p:s, c:s and b:s are arbitrary.

EDIT:

It is not a tree but rather a [bipartite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)

Comment: Your image suggests that there are branches available from every parent to every child. Do you assume this?

Comment: Do you already have a data structure to represent this?

Comment: @dhill - Does it? Parent node p1 does not branch to child c0.

Comment: Also, this is not a tree, but rather a bipartite DAG.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y - A what now? Please paste a Wikipedia reference or similar. ;) As for data structure, consider b as an object with variables p and c, like `b[0].p = 0`.

Comment: @Theodor: I meant a [bipartite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y - I agree, this it what it is. I'll edit.

Comment: I am verily confused: In your example graphic, branches b3 and b2 share the same parent and children, which is converse to the rule "two branches can not share parent and/or child". Any chance of updating the graphic ?

Comment: @Richard - The branches in the graph are _hypothetical_ branches. I'll add this in the question.

Comment: @Richard b3 and b2 have mirror parent, children. What are you talking about?

Comment: What software did you use to produce the plot?

Comment: @Muhammad - MS Visio 2010. If your a student you can sometimes get a free student licence from MSDN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. There are lot's of micro-optimizations that could be made but their efficacy would depend on the sizes involved.

```
import collections as co
import itertools as it

def unique(list_):
    return len(set(list_)) == len(list_)

def get_combos(branches):
    by_parent = co.defaultdict(list)

    for branch in branches:
        by_parent[branch.p].append(branch)

    combos = it.product(*by_parent.values())

    return it.ifilter(lambda x: unique([b.c for b in x]), combos)
```

I'm pretty sure that this is at least hitting optimal complexity as I don't see a way to avoid looking at every combination that is unique by parent.

Comment: I think you meant to have the arg to get_combos be branches, otherwise for branch in branches will throw an exception.

Comment: @Philip Good looking out. Fixed.

Comment: what is `branches` meant to be?  what python type?  what contents?

Comment: ^ i now see that this is addressed in the comments.  still, it'd be nice to have it stated in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) combinatoric generators:

- product()
- permutations()
- combinations()
- combinations_with_replacement()

Looks like you can write an iterator to achieve what you want.