# combinatorics in ruby with hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, combinatorics

Is there a **built in function** or **convention** for when you want to do combinations of states concisely?

Given the following:

```
{
  animal: [:dog, :cat],
  disposition: [:grumpy, :hungry, :sleepy]
}
```

I want to make:

```
[
  {animal: :dog, disposition: :grumpy},
  {animal: :dog, disposition: :hungry},
  {animal: :dog, disposition: :sleepy},
  {animal: :cat, disposition: :grumpy},
  {animal: :cat, disposition: :hungry},
  {animal: :cat, disposition: :sleepy}
]
```

taking any number of input states, i.e. more than 2.

Others must have solved this before me in an elegant fashion?

Python has an array way of doing it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095749/combinatorics-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786264/all-possible-combinations-from-a-hash-of-arrays-in-ruby) should work.

> [{:animal=>:dog, :disposition=>:grumpy}, {:animal=>:dog,
>   :disposition=>:hungry}, {:animal=>:dog, :disposition=>:sleepy},
>   {:animal=>:cat, :disposition=>:grumpy}, {:animal=>:cat,
>   :disposition=>:hungry}, {:animal=>:cat, :disposition=>:sleepy}]

Comment: combinations = input.values[0].product(*input.values[1..-1]).map{|p| Hash[input.keys.zip p]}

Answer (score 2):

intial hash:

```
a={  
  animal: [:dog, :cat],  
  disposition: [:grumpy, :hungry, :sleepy]  
}  
b= a[:animal].product(a[:disposition]).collect do |c|
  {animal: c[0], disposition: c[1]}
end
```